# xdg-open block until spawned process is killed

Tags: bash, xdg-open

I have a lot of documents to view, and I'd like to view them one by one, so the next opens when I close the previous.

I've done this with evince before, with

```
for i in `ls | grep .pdf`; do evince $i; done
```

However doing the same with xdg-open fails because xdg-open does not block like evince does.

Is there a way to run the same for loop, but with xdg-open, so that when I close the application that was opened, the next iteration of the for loop runs?

Comment: short answer: no. long answer: modify the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a clean way, so this is a work-around; open each file then run a busy-loop waiting for "the" matching process to exit. I've also updated your `for` loop so that you're not parsing ls and are quoting the filename parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.pdf
do
  xdg-open "$i"
  t=$(tty)
  t=${t##/dev/}
  s=$(ps -o session= -p $$)
  while pgrep -f "$i" --terminal "$t" --uid "$(id -u)" --session "$s" >/dev/null 2>&1
  do
    sleep 1
  done
done
```

The assumption here is that xdg-open will open the file; that process gets forked off by the desktop environment and control returns to the script. The script then gathers the tty, session, and current user ID and asks `pgrep` to look for (the) process matching all of these criteria:

- full process name includes the filename from the loop
- the associated terminal is the one we're running from
- the UID of the process matches ours
- the process session matches ours

... all in an attempt to catch only the corresponding process that xdg-open launched.

When that process no longer exists, we continue with the `for` loop on to the next file.

If the one-second delay is too long, you could replace that (on Linux) with a sub-second sleep, or a simple `:` for no waiting at all.

Comment: This is an awesome solution! A little hacky but it gets the job done. Very smart.

Comment: Thank you! Don't feel rushed to accept my (or any first) answer; I'm not an expert at desktop environments, so there may be a better way.

Comment: Unfortunately this will fail if the file is opened by an existing process. You can see this happen *e.g.* with `gedit`, if that’s the default editor for text files: start `gedit`, then `xdg-open` a text file; the file will open in `gedit`, and the above script won’t match anything.

Comment: @StephenKitt would the gedit process have to have started from the same tty/session, too?

Comment: That’s not sufficient, because the file name doesn’t show up on the command line of the running process.